# Can dynamic header response be made in nginx?

Tags: nginx

Can nginx create & respond with dynamic header value?

The propose is to get a file-version via HEAD request where nginx would add the version value to the response header. eg:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 14003
content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 09:52:55 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 18 Feb 2020 09:27:14 GMT
server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-firefox-spdy: h2
version: 0.7.4
```

Comment: Sure, with the [`add_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Thank you. The version is not static. It has to be read from the corresponding file. How can it be done?

Comment: First possible approach: generate this file as nginx `map` block, include it into the main nginx configuration file, reload nginx configuration every tine this file changed. Second possible approach: use openresty or ngx-lua-module, write some script, use it response after doing [subrequest](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture).